# pgfplots: polaraxis | polar | unable to add annotation (\draw, \node)

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

*I think, that I miss the obvious!*

- I want to create a (empty) polar diagram with the `pgfplots` package.
- I want to add some **custom annotations** etc. using `tikz` commands (`\draw` or `\node`, for example).
- **Problem:** It seems, that my custom annotations are not rendered?!

---

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} % Problem also occurs in "article" class.

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % Does not seem to be relevant to my issue.
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

% Nice sans-serif font, irrelevant to the question :)
\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}
    [
        % Options
        width = 120mm,
        height = 120mm,
        scale only axis, % Does not seem to be relevant to my issue.    
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 360,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        yticklabels = {},
        ylabel = {ylabel},
        xlabel = {xlabel},
    ]
    % \addplot etc.
    % No effect?!
    \node at (0,0) {Annotation};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you have confused `pgfplots` by allowing for negative radii with `ymin = -1`. If you use only nonnegative boundaries, `ymin=0` say, you get.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

% Nice sans-serif font, irrelevant to the question :)
%\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}
    [
        % Options
        width = 120mm,
        height = 120mm,
        scale only axis,    
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 360,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 1,
        yticklabels = {},
        ylabel = {ylabel},
        xlabel = {xlabel},
    ]
    % \addplot etc.
    % No effect?!
    \node at (0,0) {Annotation};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OMG! How do I get then a yline that goes from left to right (180° to 0° in the picture)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Would adding `\draw (0,1) -- (180,1);` be acceptable for you?

Comment: Yes, if this is the "clean" approach. To change the axis seems more natural to me. I naturally assumed that `ymin = -1` makes sense and the output also looked good :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I think it is cleaner than negative radii, I think. ;-)

Comment: Next question will be about *imaginary* radii :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I think we need to wait to v1.17 for that. ;-)

Comment: (sorry, forgot to accept)